# Use Async, Await with VS2013 Target - .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with a third party API that uses `.NET 4`. I would like to use **Async/Await** features in my class library. I installed `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` from NuGet. I have a few questions regarding deployment:

1) Upon installing `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, I have a number of references added to my project (`Microsoft.Threading.Tasks`, `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`..). Also there is an app.config file that is created. What are the deployment requirements?

2) How would I deploy the app.config file for a class library that goes in the installation directory of the 3rd party app. Do I need to add xml from app.config to the application's config?

3) Do I need to install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` on all projects that reference that project mentioned?

Environment:

Visual Studio Express 2013
.NET 4

Comment: Why was this closed by a single person? I do not think this was too broad.

Comment: @CoryNelson if you have a badge for a tag like [tag:c#] or [tag:.net] you can close a question as a duplicate with a single vote. EDIT: however looking at the history the single person was a moderator so they can do that too for all of the close reasons, not just duplicates. Most likely someone flagged this question for a moderator and the moderator just judged too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Upon installing Microsoft.Bcl.Async, I have a number of references added to my project (Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions..). Also there is an app.config file that is created. What are the deployment requirements?

Deploy the dlls and the app.config.

> 2) How would I deploy the app.config file for a class library that goes in the installation directory of the 3rd party app. Do I need to add xml from app.config to the application's config?

Yes.

> 3) Do I need to install Microsoft.Bcl.Async on all projects that reference that project mentioned?

Possibly. As a best practice, install Microsoft.Bcl.Build in all your projects. That will generate build warnings notifying you if you need to install references to your other projects.